# Android material.textfield.TextInputEditText как убрать курсор во время скролинга длинного текста?

Tags: android

Есть `material.textfield.TextInputEditText` в него попадает длинный текст, на 30-40 строк. Во время прокрутки текста появляется фокус и курсор, которые мешают скролить. Нашёл решение, которое полностью отключает фокус и курсор, для этого необходимо передать `textEdit.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);` курсор отключается полностью во время скролинга, но как включить его обратно непонятно. Получается я проскролил, курсор пропал и больше его нет, невозможно вводить текст.

```java
textEdit.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
        view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        
        //Выключаю курсор 
        textEdit.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        textEdit.clearFocus();

        if ((event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {

            view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)

        } else {
            //performClick()
        }
     
        return@setOnTouchListener false
     }
```

```xml
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/filledTextField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="top"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
        android:maxLength="2048"
        android:minLines="11"
        android:maxLines="11"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ с опозданием, но есть такое решение (возможно костыль). В главном активити переопределяем метод:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    currentFocus?.let { currFocus ->
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(this)
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currFocus.windowToken, 0)
        if (currentFocus != null) {
            currentFocus!!.clearFocus()
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

Как только вы кликнете куда угодно кроме поля с текстом, у следующего фокус уберется и он перестанет быть активным до следующего вашего клика по нему

Параметры TextInputLayout:

```html
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="top|start"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    app:textInputLayoutFocusedRectEnabled="false" />
               </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```